BankId Opens the app on PC but it still cant find a bankid installed
i got this code `
 if (GetBankIdLoginType() == BankIdTypeEnum.BankIDFil || GetBankIdLoginType() == BankIdTypeEnum && IsSameDevice == true) { 
    var url = "bankid:///?autostarttoken=" + result.Response.AutoStartToken + "&redirect=null";
     window.location.href = url;
     
 } else if (GetBankIdLoginType() == BankIdTypeEnum.MobiltBankID && IsSameDevice && IsMobile) {
     var redirectUri = "https://app.bankid.com/?autostarttoken=" + result.Response.AutoStartToken + "&redirect=null;
         window.location.href = redirectUri;
 }

And the application opens the bankid on file application imidielty after i have pressed the button login button on the site. But it cant find the installed file containing my bankid.  i have tried to use iframe and also window.location.open(url, '_blank') and nothing seems to work. I have verified on activelogin.demo site that my bankid on file is correctly installed and it works to login on it.but no mather what i have tried i cant get it to find my bankid from my site.
i have also tried to check the autostarttoken is correct and yes, it works when i surf in to the site on the phone, then the bankid app opens and i can sign and login.
